# command line to parse the timestamp and return most recent log filename

Tags: shell, unix, logging, command-line, timestamp

I have log files , that are stored in the following format-

```
<filename>+time.strftime('%m%d%y_%H%M%S') + '.log'
```

Example

```
test090815_080459.log
test090915_052134.log
test090915_080836.log 
test090815_090503.log
```

[EDIT] I was initially thinking of parsing the log file names to reconstruct the timestamp.But found a simpler solution to what I was thinking before. Posted below.

these are stored under some ./log directory. 
How do I extract the most recent log file name using a command line on linux?
Note : the filename may end in a number too (example, test_v2)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any code we might base our answers on ? "Code this for me" type of questions are likely to be ignored or remain unanswered. Do you search for a single command or do you want to write a shell script ?

Comment: answered below @Marged

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my own question. It was pretty simple actually ,

```
ls -1t  <scriptname>*| head -1
```

should go with the implicit timestamps rather than trying to parse the timestamp in the log file names.

Comment: and what happens when your last log was written 3 days ago ? Or someone touched an older file ? Your solution can work in your scenario but risks remain (I only named two)